# R: merging sorted numeric input into intervals

Tags: r

I have a sorted numeric input that looks like this:

```
1    1    10
1    12   18
1    16   30
1    30   40
2    35   45

DF = structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), V2 = c(1L, 12L, 16L, 
30L, 35L), V3 = c(10L, 18L, 30L, 40L, 45L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

It's sorted by the first column and then the second.  Now I'm trying to design an efficient function in R (efficient because my input is hundreds of thousands of rows) that can merge the overlapping rows, e.g., rows 2 and 3 are overlapping in three places (16, 17, and 18), while rows 3 and 4 are overlapping at one location (30), while row 5 starts with 2 so it's separate from the rest.  All in all, I want to get:

```
1    1    10
1    12   40 
2    35   45
```

However, I'm struggling with incorporating a parameter that says "if two rows are close enough to each other, e.g., within 5 units), then merge them, otherwise don't.  In this case, I want to get:

```
1    1    40
2    35   45
```

because 12-10 = 2 < 5.  But if the parameter is set to 1, then the output would just be the original:

```
1    1    10
1    12   40 
2    35   45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

th = 5
DT[, g := cumsum(V2 - shift(V3, fill = first(V2)) >= th), by=V1]
DT[, .(V2 = first(V2), V3 = last(V3)), by=.(V1, g = rleid(V1, g))]

#    V1 g V2 V3
# 1:  1 1  1 40
# 2:  2 2 35 45

# same code with th = 1

#    V1 g V2 V3
# 1:  1 1  1 10
# 2:  1 2 12 40
# 3:  2 3 35 45
```

Comment: Briefly, what is `setDT(DT)`, I'm getting `Error: Can not find symbol DT`.  Did you mean `setDT(DF)`?

Comment: @warship Oh right. Yes, if you use `DF` everywhere I have `DT`, it should work. Alternately, you could write `DT = data.table(DF)` and skip the `setDT` step (which just converts a data.frame to a data.table).

Comment: Just curious, is there a difference between `setDT(DF)`, `DT = data.table(DF)`, and `DT = as.data.table(DF)`?  `setDT(DF)` seems to be the most efficient since it's changing the input by reference so no copying is done, right?

Comment: @warship Yeah. `setDT(DF)` will alter `DF` in place, in contrast with most R functions that don't have "side effects" like this. The other two options will create a new object, `DT`, leaving `DF` alone; they should be the same for most inputs, but their docs (`?as.data.table`, `?data.table`) may cover any subtle differences.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your toy example

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2),
             X1=c(1,12,16,30,35),
             X2=c(10,18,30,40,45))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%                                  # group wise operation by ID
  mutate(lg=lag(X2+5,default=head(X2,1))) %>%     # for comparison, offset X2 column by +1 row and add value of 5
  mutate(lt=lg<=X2) %>%                           # check if lg <= X2 
  mutate(group=cumsum(lt != lag(lt,default=head(lt,1)))) %>%    # make groups based on logical test in lt
  group_by(ID,group) %>%
  summarise(X1=min(X1), X2=max(X2))               # summarise data as min and max of X1 and X2 respectively
```

Output

```
     ID group    X1    X2
1     1     0     1    40
2     2     0    35    45
```

Comment: I guess you can do a single `mutate` call with a sequence of mutations in it.

Comment: You're right of course. I list them step wise to make it more understandable. That's one advantage of data.table verbs I've noticed...it seems more concise